# how to compile java

Tags: command-line, java

If I type in:

```
javac D:\JavaTest\Hello.java
```

Here is what I get:

[image]

I'm a beginner in Java. I installed the Java SE Development Kit 6u22 from Sun's website.

I tried writing this code in Notepad:

```
 class Hello {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Welcome to the world of Java Programming.");
    } // method main
 } // class Hello
```

I tried to compile it in a Command Prompt following [these](http://www.loirak.com/prog/java.php) instructions.

To compile and run this program, you need to have installed JDK and added a line to your path statement referring to the directory of where it was install + \bin. (e.g. path `%path%;c:\jdk\bin;`)

- Type this file into Notepad or a similar text editor
- Save it as Hello.java (class name + .java)
- Drop to a Command Prompt
- Type `javac Hello.java` (e.g. `javac C:\work\Hello.java`)
- Type `java Hello` (e.g. `java C:\work\Hello`)
- Watch the magic

I got an error message that 'javac' is not recognized as an external or internal command, operable program or batch file.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This is probably an issue with the path variable for the environment you're working in. If you are not using an IDE, you probably just need to add the location of javac.exe to your system PATH variable.

Comment: what do you mean MaQleod? I made another folder on my D drive which I named it as JavaTest so when I compiled it in command prompt this is what I typed: javac D:\JavaTest\Hello.java and I got the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the proper location of the javac binary to your PATH. See directions on [the Oracle website](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).

After updating your PATH variable, open a new command prompt window. The old ones will not work as it rereads the variable upon starting.

Comment: @John: ok will try this one and will go back once it's ok. thanks

Comment: exactly what I said. This should do the trick.

Comment: I am reading the link from the Oracle website, and sorry it seems I can't understand, I tried copying the file Hello.java in the folder C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\javac and it is still the same error

Comment: @tin, you do not copy java files to the folder... You add that folder to your PATH. See this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hl-zzrqQoSE&feature=related

Comment: @tintincute If you did default installation of 32bit JDK, just add "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin" to your path if you are using 64bit version of windows or "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin" if you are using 32bit version of windows,

Comment: @AndrejaKo: wait how will I know that I'm using 32bit or 64bit? I'm using win xp professional windows 2002 service pack 3

Comment: @John T: will watch the video now.

Comment: @tintincute Then it's 32bit. Video is for Vista, so what you need to do is to go to Control Panel-> System->Advanced and follow instructions in the video. You could also find under environment variables "System variables" and find Path there. Go to its end and see if it ends with ;. if it doesn't add ;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin; if it does, then skip first ;

Comment: Or simply go to the start menu and click "Run", then type in `sysdm.cpl` and hit Enter. On the Advanced tab, you will see "Environment Variables" button on the bottom.

Comment: @John T: I did it. Thanks. But I'm trying to figure out, how will I know if it's 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: @tintincute Go to run and type cmd. Windows XP is actually Windows NT version 5.1, so if you get version 5.1.xxxx, you have 32bit. There's no real 64bit version of windows XP. Instead the 64 bit version of XP is modified Windows 2003 whose version number should be 5.2.xxxx

Answer (score 2):

You sure you've installed the JDK? Have you restarted since installing it? As a side note, thats the correct way to do it, so I can't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: yes I installed the JDK. I can find it in my C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22. I actually have 4 folders here. How can I restart it?

Comment: I meant restarted the computer, have you done that?

Comment: no. do I need to restart?

Answer (score 1):

I create a gojava script in my home directory. It just adds the java SDK directory to the PATH. This isn't the approved method but I dislike having a huge PATH.

Open a command prompt window from Start menu or a desktop shortcut ...

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6002]
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\RGB> javac
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\RGB> gojava

C:\Users\RGB> javac
Usage: javac <options> <source files>

C:\Users\RGB> type gojava.bat
PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin
```

You could add `cd C:\work\` to that batch file.

Even better, you could install Eclipse or Netbeans.

Comment: what is RGB here? Do I need to create this folder?

Comment: do I need to create a folder work under C:\?

Comment: You can put your Java source anywhere convenient. For example you could put it in "My Documents/Java" or "C:\Workspace" or anywhere that suits you. Consider that the "Java base directory". Java source code is normally arranged in "packages" based on reverse DNS domain names. E.g. com.tintincute.lottogame, com.tintincute.killerapp. The main java for this would be in <basedir>/com/tintincute/killerapp/Killer.Java.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the image, and that is actually normal. When nothing displayed, it compiled fine!

Now you just have to run it.

When you compiled it:

```
c:\>javac d:\javatest\Hello.java
```

When it displayed nothing, it worked. It created a file `hello.class`.

Now you type:

```
c:\>java Hello
```

and it should display the output.